# Google Cloud Storage + CDN + CNAME configuration

Tags: csv, google-cloud-storage, cdn

We need to store static files in Google CDN, for example like this way: https://cdn.website.com/css/main.css where files will be on Google Cloud Storage.

What we have done:

1. Created load balancing + bucket cdn.website.com
2. Setup CNAME cdn.website.com to Google Cloud bucket IP
3. Created storage cdn.website.com
4. Have transferred files to Storage via TSV-file https://www.website.com/tsv/some.tsv

Once we have imported files via TSV, the folder "www.website.com" will created automatically in Google Cloud Storage.
And the final URL will get like
https://cdn.website.com/www.website.com/css/main.css

We dont need sub-folder www.website.com in storage (its created after import of TSV-file). 
Any solution?
Thanks!

> When an object located at http(s)://[HOSTNAME]:[PORT]/[URL_PATH] is
>   transferred to Cloud Storage, the name of the object in Cloud Storage
>   is [HOSTNAME]/[URL_PATH].

The question is: how to remove "HOSTNAME/" from url path.

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyFFc.png)

Comment: How many files? If it's a few tens of thousands or less, looping over them with gsutil and copying them to a similar path with a little bash script would probably work.

Comment: gsutil is the only solution, TSV will not work.